# Can selinux log an application owner name?

Tags: logs, selinux, sftp

So I've set up selinux to log all file access operations in a certain directory. Here's some sample log output when doing an ls from sftp:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1338465611.221:356): avc:  granted  { getattr } for  pid=5973 comm="sftp-server" path="/polog" dev=dm-0 ino=1966081 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:polog_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

sftp in this case is running as user1, is there a way to have selinux log this username as well or should I be taking a different approach?

Here's my policy files:

---polog.te---

```
policy_module(polog, 1.0.14)

require {
    type fs_t;
        type unconfined_t;
        type sshd_t;
        type setfiles_t;
        class filesystem associate;
        class dir relabelto;
}

type polog_t;

#============= polog_t ==============

allow polog_t fs_t:filesystem associate;
allow unconfined_t polog_t:dir relabelto;
allow setfiles_t polog_t:dir relabelto;

#====================================

auditallow unconfined_t polog_t : file *;
auditallow unconfined_t polog_t : dir *;

allow unconfined_t polog_t : file *;
allow unconfined_t polog_t : dir *;
```

---

---polog.fc---

```
/polog(/.*)?            gen_context(system_u:object_r:polog_t)
```

Comment: AFAIK your answer is https://fedorahosted.org/setroubleshoot/

Answer (score 0):

SELinux does not work with classic DAC usernames, and thus you won't be able to display that kind of information this way. You should have a look at the audit subsystem and the  `auditd` daemon. You will have to write a specific set of rules (not SELinux related) to log access to those files.

Some links to help you get started:

- [Slides about the Audit Subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/audit_ids_2011.pdf);
- [Defining Audit Rules (RHEL 6 documentation)](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Defining_Audit_Rules_and_Controls.html);
- audit.rules(7) (i.e. `man 7 audit.rules`).